# Restangular - How to override Error Interceptors

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am using **AngularJS v1.2.16** with **Restangular v1.4.0**, and would like to know if it's possible to override the ErrorInterceptor. If yes, how? if no, how can I work it around?

I've configured an error Interceptor like this:

```
RestangularProvider.setErrorInterceptor(
    function ( response ) {
        if ( response.status == 401 ) {
        dialogs.error("Unauthorized - Error 401", "You must be authenticated in order to access this content.")
            .result.then( function () {
                $location.path("/login");
            });
        }
        else {
            // Some other unknown Error.
            console.log( response );
            dialogs.error(response.statusText + " - Error " + response.status,
                "An unknown error has occurred.<br>Details: " + response.data);
        }
        // Stop the promise chain.
        return false;
    }
);
```

then, on another place, I make a POST call with an error handling.

```
function saveApple( apple ) {
    Restangular.all("apple/save").post( apple ).then(
        function ( response ) {
            console.log("Saved");
        },
        function ( response ) {
            // This is not being called.
            console.log("Error with status code", response.status);
        }
    );
}
```

I understand that, my "second" error handler is not being called because I'm returning `false` on the `ErrorInterceptor`.

But how can I work this around? I have lots of "REST operations" in my app, and only few of them, I want a customized behavior when something goes wrong.

So far, the only work-around I thought of, is to make the `ErrorInterceptor` return `true`, and for every other REST operations, I copy-paste the same error handler (a more general one). But this would be the last thing I would do.

Right now, is flowing like this:

- ErrorInterceptor > End.

If possible, I want it to be like this: (Only for specific methods - not all).

- ErrorInterceptor > Especific_ErrorHandler (if Exists) > End.

it can also be like this:

- Especific_ErrorHandler (if Exists) > ErrorInterceptor > End.

Either way works for me.

References:

https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#seterrorinterceptor
https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#how-can-i-handle-errors

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is your code:

```
RestangularProvider.setErrorInterceptor(
    function ( response ) {
        if ( response.status == 401 ) {
        dialogs.error("Unauthorized - Error 401", "You must be authenticated in order to access this content.")
            .result.then( function () {
                $location.path("/login");
            });
        }
        else {
            // Some other unknown Error.
            console.log( response );
            dialogs.error(response.statusText + " - Error " + response.status,
                "An unknown error has occurred.<br>Details: " + response.data);
        }
        // Stop the promise chain.
        return false;
    }
);
```

Why are you using an interceptor?
- because you want dialogs across the board for displaying error messags.

### Stopping promise chain, is it bad practice?

I don't know. Many people use error callbacks; and one use-case for error callbacks is to do some cleanup. If you kill the promise chain, how do you ensure the cleanup is done? Stopping the promise chain means your error callbacks, your `catch` blocks, and your `finally` blocks won't get called.

In the docs, the cleanup is done, you can see that `deferred.reject` is passed along.
https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#seterrorinterceptor
Maybe you misunderstood the example that was in the docs.

### Possible solution #1

```
        // DON'T stop the promise chain.
        return true;
```

### Possible solution #2

Don't handle unknown errors in the error interceptor.

```
RestangularProvider.setErrorInterceptor(
    function ( response ) {
        if ( response.status == 401 ) {
            dialogs.error("Unauthorized - Error 401", "You must be authenticated in order to access this content.")
                .result.then( function () {
                   $location.path("/login");
                });
            // Stop the promise chain.
            // all unauthorized access are handled the same.
            return false;
        }
        // Some other unknown Error.
        console.log( response );
        dialogs.error(response.statusText + " - Error " + response.status,
            "An unknown error has occurred.<br>Details: " + response.data);
        }
        // DON'T stop promise chain since error is not handled
        return true;
    }
);
```

### Possible solution #3

call `reject` when you stop the promise chain.

```
RestangularProvider.setErrorInterceptor(
    function ( response, deferred, responseHandler ) {
        if ( response.status == 401 ) {
            dialogs.error("Unauthorized - Error 401", "You must be authenticated in order to access this content.")
                .result.then( function () {
                   // continue promise chain in this callback.
                   deferred.reject("unauthorized");
                   $location.path("/login");
                });
            // Stop the promise chain here
            // all unauthorized access are handled the same.
            return false;
        }
        // Some other unknown Error.
        console.log( response );
        dialogs.error(response.statusText + " - Error " + response.status,
            "An unknown error has occurred.<br>Details: " + response.data);
        }
        // DON'T stop promise chain since error is not handled
        return true;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create custom `httpErrorHandler`.

- First you need to create a `.factory`, let's call it `httpErrorHandler`

```js
.factory('httpErrorHandler', function ($rootScope) {
  return {
    'error': function (rejection) {
      if (rejection.status === 422) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('422_error', rejection.data);
      } else if (rejection.status === 403) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('403_error', rejection.data);
      } else {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('unknown', rejection.data);
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
}
```

- Then register that factory to the `$httpProvider` interceptors

```js
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpErrorHandler');
});
```

Then just catch that `$rootScope` events anywhere in the application and handle them, or add some logic inside the interceptor.

I hope this will work as expected.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I don't know if it's against the rules to write this comment.. but anyways... I will take a look at your answer carefully tomorrow or after tomorrow, I just moved in to a new place... but glad to know there is a way to solve this. Thanks.