# How to Override Global Error Handler by some methods in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-http-interceptors, custom-error-handling

I have implemented Global error handling in my Angular 7 application which is working fine to handle all errors.

```
export class RequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {  
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // My code
    });

    return next.handle(request)
        .pipe(
            map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
             //
                return event;
            }),
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {                    
                if (error.status === 403) {                                                
                   // code here
                }

                if (error.status === 401) {
                   // code here
                }

                if (error.status === 0){

                }                                        
            }));
        }
}
```

Here my question was " How can we override this Global Catcherror method by some methods in the component and handle error in the component method Catch block itself".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28010548/restangular-how-to-override-error-interceptors might help